# Move quick actions to main context menu

Tags: finder, automator

I'm using macOS Sonoma 14.0

I've found [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445872/is-it-possible-to-move-quick-action-from-the-separate-tab-directly-to-context-me/453044?newreg=3d010e7106f1406baef7623a642026cc) question, but the accepted solution doesn't seem to work on the new macOS, the action disappears from quick actions and that's it. So, is there a way to move quick action items to the main context of the Finder **without using any 3rd party programs**?

Comment: I don't think so: but if there were a third-party app that could configure the menu in this way, would that be a problem? (There was such an app for Services, that toggled between putting them in a submenu, and not.)

Comment: I was mainly curious if the old method described in the link still works in some modified way.